# Open only files containing a specific string and then replace on Linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line, replace, sed, find

I have been using a simple find command to search hundreds of html files and then replace some simple text within each file.

1. To find and list files containing the search string.

   ```
   find . -iname '*php' | xargs grep 'search-string' -sl
   ```

Which gives me a simple list of files like.

```
    ./javascript_open_new_window_form.php
    ./excel_large_number_error.php
    ./linux_vi_string_substitution.php
    ./email_reformat.php
    ./online_email_reformat.php
```

1. To search and replace the string I use.

   ```
   sed -i 's/search-string/replace-string/' ./javascript_open_new_window_form.php
   sed -i 's/search-string/replace-string/' ./excel_large_number_error.php
   sed -i 's/search-string/replace-string/' ./linux_vi_string_substitution.php
   sed -i 's/search-string/replace-string/' ./email_reformat.php
   sed -i 's/search-string/replace-string/' ./online_email_reformat.php
   ```

So my question is... how can I combine the 2 commands so I do not manually have to copy and paste the file names each time.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this :

```
find . -iname '*php' | xargs grep 'search-string' -sl | while read x; do echo $x; sed -i 's/search-string/replace-string/' $x; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it again to another `xargs`. Just make the second `xargs` use `-n 1` to run the command one by one for each file in the input, rather then the default behavior. Like this:

```
find . -iname '*php' | xargs grep 'search-string' -sl | xargs -n 1 sed -i 's/search-string/replace-string/'
```